# How to move two images at a time in ios

Tags: scrollview

i have array of images. when i move one image remaining images also need yo move in the same direction of first image.
this is my code.

```
(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
   AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
   float y = myScroll.contentOffset.y + recipeImageView.frame.origin.y;
   float x = myScroll.contentOffset.x + recipeImageView.frame.origin.x;
   NSLog(@"x Position is :%f , y position is : %f",x,y);

   for(int i=0;i<=[app phhhhh].count;i++){
      UICollectionViewCell *cell = 
         [[UICollectionViewCell alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 
         (self.view.frame.size.height-imageHeight)/2-50, imageWidth , 649)];
      recipeImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, imageWidth , 649)];

      NSIndexPath * indexPath = [_collectionView indexPathForCell:cell];
      NSLog(@"rsdf");
      recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[app phhhhh] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

      [cell addSubview:recipeImageView];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x, y) animated:YES];
```